# Wrong typescript generated file

Tags: protobuf.js

The typescript generated file is no more valid

The enums are generated into a namespace
And the interface are no more included

I am using typescript 6.8.9 but I think it is a dependancy issue.

Are you also experiencing this issue ?

Comment: we need more precision, you can post parts of your code.

Comment: here is a test.proto
```
    syntax = "proto3";
    
    enum enum_t {
        ENUM_0 = 0;
        ENUM_1 = 1;
        ENUM_2 = 2;
        ENUM_3 = 3;
    }
```

And the generated code is
```
/** enum_t enum. */
namespace enum_t {
    let ENUM_0: number;
    let ENUM_1: number;
    let ENUM_2: number;
    let ENUM_3: number;
}
```

instead of
```
    /** messageid_t enum. */
    enum enum_t {
        ENUM_0 = 0,
        ENUM_1 = 1,
        ENUM_2 = 2,
        ENUM_3 = 3,
    }
```